# iOS - Reload UITableView with UINavigationBar back button without popping view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

I have looked everywhere but no luck. I want the UINavigationController back button to reload my tableView until I reach a certain mark, and then pop the view. To try and make this a little more clear, I have a UITableViewController that loads directories from a server. I want the user to start at root, and then be able to navigate through a theoretical endless chain of directories, and I will reload the tableview on each cell selected.

That all works, but the backwards navigation. The NavigationController pops the view instead of taking me back a directory (reloading the tableView) as expected. How can I override the back button to just refresh the tableView?

Comment: I think it'll make more sense in terms of user experience to push into a new table view controller if you're displaying a folder structure, like the Dropbox app, for example. The navigation controller stack works incredible well for this and you could essentially reuse and push into the same table view controller class  endlessly (based on the folder tree). Just my two cents.

Comment: interesting. Is there an example somewhere as to how they do this? Just add the new tableviewcontroller on to the navigationbar stack ad didselectcell?

Comment: Just push the same UITableViewController class and tell it which `dir` to load. Just because it's the same class doesn't mean you cannot initialize them from the same class.